# js validation of not null field

Tags: javascript, validation

I have done a login page. I want my js validateForm()function to alert a user if they have left out the username or password. This is the code I have got at the moment.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["username"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Please enter username");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<div class="users form">
<br>


<form name="myform" action="Employees/login" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" >
<?php

    if (isset($error)) {


    echo "<p style='color:red;font-size: 20px''>Username or Password is invalid. Please try again.</p>";


        }?>
        <p>Enter Username:
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" style="height: 25px;width: 160px;"/></p>
        <br><br>
        <p>Enter Password:
        <input type="password" name="password"  placeholder="password" style="height: 25px;width: 160px;"/></p>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" style="height:35px;width:100px;font-size: 18px; align:center;" value="Sign in">

   </form>
</div>
```

At the moment it is not working, and I think the problem is with the code line "var x=document.forms["myForm"]["username"].value;" Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is `forms["myForm"]`, you used an uppercase `F`, when actually your form name is all lowercase so it should be:

```
var x=document.forms["myform"]["username"].value;
//                      ^ lowercase
```

---

Not part of the problem, but you might prefer to use unobtrusive JavaScript to set the `onsubmit` handler instead of in the HTML attribute:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.forms["myform"].onsubmit = validateForm;
};
```

Now, in `validateForm` you can use `this` instead of finding the form manually.

```
function validateForm()
{
    var x = this["username"].value;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works now. By the way is there any way I can add styles to the alert box? I want the text in the alert to be in red and in a bigger size.

Comment: The alert box can't be styled, have a look into Boostrap Modals which are much nicer than alerts, and can be styled: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals